# Yii CAdvancedArBehavior unable to save a model with relation right after load

Tags: php, mysql, yii, many-to-many

I got 2 models:

class `Mail` with relation:

```
'relAttachments' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'File', 'rel_mail_file(rel_mail, rel_file)'),
```

`Mail` has the [AdvancedArBehavior](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/cadvancedarbehavior/) extension attached so i can link Attachments to it with a 1-liner, which i do like this:

```
$mail->relAttachments = $attachments; // $attachments is an array of ids for `File` models
```

class `Mailque` with relation:

```
'relMail' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Mail', 'rel_mail'),
```

Once i saved and linked Mail and Mailque, i run this code after sending out the mail:

```
$mail = Mail::model()->findByPk($id);
$mailModel = $mail->relMail;

var_dump(count($mailModel->relAttachments));  // outputs 1

$mailModel->sent = time();
$mailModel->save();
//$mail->delete();
```

The call to save() yields the following error:

```
exception 'CException' with message 'Property "File.rel_file" is not defined.' in ...\framework\base\CComponent.php:131
```

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: You are trying to set File.rel_file somewhere but that property doesn't exists. Where do you call `save`? What attributes are you assigning to the File model?

Comment: sorry for the confusion.. i wanted to replace received with sent, but replaced save.. made some edit now. i am only setting sent. rel_file is from the Many_Many relation that AdvancedArBehavior is updating, which is not missing, just in another table.. something is just going wrong and i can't see where. The error occurs inside the AdvancedArBehavior.

Comment: Haven't use AdvancedArBehavior, but you can try [With Related Behavior](https://github.com/yiiext/with-related-behavior) if you have some issues with that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look like you need to define a public variable in File model.

try this... in File class

```
public $rel_file = 'id';
```

Comment: +1 oddly enough this works... but isn't this a bug at AdvancedArBehavior? It should know that rel_file is not an attribute of Mail but of a relation. Also the same error doesn't happen if i save the same model twice. For this to be acceptable as answer, why does this only happen when the model is freshly loaded? BUG in ARB or my code?

Comment: yes, it seems a bug in AdvancedArBehavior. this line seems a culprit.
`$foreignobject = $foreignobject->{$foreignobject->$relation['m2mForeignField']};` 
where $relation['m2mForeignField'] is 'rel_file'  and foreignobject is File object.

Comment: That is seriously messed up.  I was having a similar problem, but only with one controller, and I can't figure out what is different about my update method that was causing this. Declaring public vars like this seems to have solved the bug, but would like to know what was causing it because this is a total hack. btw mine was not involving a file object.  I spent all day messing around with this. +1000 internets for you, SuVeRa

Answer (score 0):

Or you can kill it at the source :)

in /protected/extensions/CAdvancedArBehavior.php

Comment out line 165 and replace it as follows:

```
// $foreignobject = $foreignobject->{$foreignobject->$relation['m2mForeignField']};
$foreignobject = $foreignobject->getPrimaryKey();
```

I got this patch on the Yii forums and it solved my problem without the need for SuReVa's hack. I did a bit of testing by saving and loading a few m2m model relations, and seems fine, although I haven't tested it extensively.